# vaadin view open in new window or tab

Tags: java, view, vaadin

How can I open a view in a new window or tab?
Currently I am using

```
getUI().getNavigator().navigateTo(viewname)
```

which works fine for switching of the view in same browser window.
But I want to open a certain view in new tab/browser(chrom/IE, etc). How can I do that

Comment: I recommend you put your view in a separate UI and use the BrowserWindowOpener. https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/advanced/advanced-windows.html

Comment: You may find this example useful too: https://github.com/apm78/vaadin-basics/tree/master/src/main/java/de/akquinet/engineering/vaadin/exercises/theming

Comment: In fact there is a predefined Vaadin object called Window for that. Place your view in the window and attach the window to your current view whenever you want to open it.

Comment: For Vaadin 8, see similar Question: [*Generate an HTML page, and open in a new window, from a Vaadin 8 app*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51691041/642706). Instead of passing an `ExternalResource` as seen there, pass the `Class` object of your UI subclass, `MyOtherUI.class`. This is explained on the [*Handling Browser Windows*](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/advanced/advanced-windows.html) page of the manual.